# Random double-quote character in jsp output

Tags: jsp, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

I have a .jsp page I'm compiling with ant and deploying to a Tomcat 7 server. A couple of times the output source document has a double-quote character added at a point where it shouldn't be added. It seems to persist through multiple compiles and deploys, but they've always gone away after a while.

Here is a section of the jsp:

```
  <form action="SetDocName" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="text" name="new-doc-name" /> <input type="submit" value="<%= uiStrings.getString("change_doc_name") %>" />
  </form>
```

and here's the final output:

```
  <form action="SetDocName" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="text" name="new-doc-name" /> <input type="submit" value="Change document name" />"
  </form>
```

notice the double-quote next to the second input element.

Any idea what's going on here? It's not a major problem at the moment, but it is puzzling.

Comment: I'm editing my JSP in Eclipse, with the Web Page Editor plugin (2.3.1.v20100906-4609oB5855L6N org.eclipse.jst.webpageeditor.feature.feature.group). I tried selecting the whitespece where the character was showing up and replacing it with new whitespace and that seems to have made it go away (unless it was just due to go away anyway).

Comment: @skaffman a previous draft had a wsdl tag on it, that draft came up when I started writing this, but I removed the wsdl tag before submitting. Are you still seeing a wsdl tag?

Comment: Just noticed the heading, must have missed that. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never really got to the bottom of this completely, in the absence of an explanation I guess the fix is the closest to an answer:

*My comment:* "The issue seems to be the web page editor plugin somehow inserting some sort of character that shows up as whitespace in the editor but is interpreted differently by Tomcat. Replacing the whitespace with new whitespace fixed it and it hasn't happened since."

Answer (score 0):

That uiString you are using seems to be messing things up I would try the following (single quotes):

value='<%= uiStrings.getString("change_doc_name") %>'

Comment: That should not form a problem. JSP is processed at webserver, not at webbrowser. Have you read OP's comments on the question?

Comment: The JSP is processed in the servlet container, and it seems to me it is a problem with the parsing done by uiString at the server

Comment: I'm fairly confident it isn't anything to do with the UI strings - I have dozens of them between double quotes like this in this application, and a couple of hundred in another.

Comment: The issue seems to be the web page editor plugin somehow inserting some sort of character that shows up as whitespace in the editor but is interpreted differently by Tomcat. Replacing the whitespace with new whitespace fixed it and it hasn't happened since.